# How do I use memcached to invalidate updated records?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, memcached

On our site, we have a variety of data collections. We pull a lot of records by ID, and we also have some records that are paginated content.

We are caching our queries using memcached - we essentially serialize the query array and then `md5()` it. This provides us a key to use for this specific query. However, this query can return multiple records - and if one of those records is changed, we want to invalidate the cached query that resulted in that record being returned.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I toyed with the idea of having two instances of memcached, with one acting as like an index server, if you will.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can address this (if I read you correctly), is to store collection of IDs with the MD5 key and then those rows separately. So for example if you end up querying for collection and it returned 10 results, you would save the IDs only by the MD5 of the query key. For each of the ID, you will then query the database and get the full details, which are individually stored in memcached. When individual items are updates, it's now easier to invalidate the memcache entry. And these records updates wont effect the collection now as you only have the IDs stored. Hope this helps.